# How do I get a reference to an array?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

This gives me back the string "$array_colors" but what I want is its content. How do I get a reference to array $array_colors?

```
<?php

$array_colors = array("blue","green");
$v = "_colors";
$a = '$array'.$v;
var_dump($a)
?>
```

Comment: `$$a`.  Use 2 `$`s.  It's called ["variable variables"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (also, remove the `$` from inside the string).

Comment: Try to avoid doing this. Whenever you think you need variable variables, you can almost always do it better by using another level of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get a reference to an array?

Like this, `$array_colors_reference` now contains reference to `$array_colors`:

```
$array_colors = array("blue","green");
$array_colors_reference = &$array_colors;
```

You can try:

```
$array_colors = array("blue","green");
$array_colors_reference = &$array_colors;

unset($array_colors_reference[0]);  
print_r($array_colors);
```

Output will be:

```
Array
(
    [1] => green
)
```